# Hibernate Query doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jdbc, oracle10g

I am using Oracle10g database.
I tried this query:

```
public List<Ods_Gis_Actel> getAll() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Ods_Gis_Actel> L = session.createQuery("from Ods_Gis_Actel").list();
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return L;
    }
```

it worked and returned the expected result.

but this query didn't work and kept returning a null value.

```
    public Ods_Gis_Actel getById(String id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Ods_Gis_Actel a = (Ods_Gis_Actel) session.get(Ods_Gis_Actel.class,new String(id));
    return a;
}
```

This is the class Ods_Gis_Actel:

```
package dao; 
public class Ods_Gis_Actel {
    private String code_actel;
    private String nom_actel;
    private String code_region;
    private String libelle_region;
}
```

My configuration files and HibernateUtil are fine and correct.

I copied the lines of the query functions from a video tutorial here everything was working fine.
Can this be a problem of compatibility of **Oracle10g** and **Hibernate**?

Comment: coud you post your Ods_Gis_Actel class?

Comment: package dao;

public class Ods_Gis_Actel {

 private String code_actel;
 private String nom_actel;
 private String code_region;
 private String libelle_region;

Comment: + all setters and getters + default constructor + constructor with all fields

Comment: Find 1 difference in your examples between query and return lines.

Comment: Mr Alexandre, why are you speaking in riddles?!

Comment: You are not committing transaction. Is that clear enough for you? Also what is the primary key in your `Ods_Gis_Actel`?

Comment: I tried commit and that didn't work. Commit , i think is to save the state of the table after a transaction, and the transaction i am using doesn't affect the table (it is a select query).

Comment: for the primary key, it's code_actel:

Comment: <hibernate-mapping>
 
    <class name="dao.Ods_Gis_Actel" table="Ods_Gis_Actel">
    
     <id name="code_actel"  column="CODE_ACTEL">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
     </id>

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are no records with your id (`String id`).
You should remove `session.beginTransaction();`

```
 Ods_Gis_Actel a = (Ods_Gis_Actel) session.get(Ods_Gis_Actel.class,id);
```

Comment: you mean that there are no line in the Table with that id?  no, i am sure there are.